# Why is continue; statement acting as break; in my code in java?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Task was to obtain the following output using loops
12456789

**My code**

```
public class Loops {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       int i = 1;
       while (i<=9){ 
           if (i==3){
               continue;
       }
            System.out.print(i);
            i++;

       }
    }
}
```

**Actual output**-
12
**Expected Output**-
12456789

Why is the output stopping at 2?
Besides, I know alternate codes for the same problem using for(:::) statement but what is the issue with this code??
Your assistance will greatly benefit me!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What do you expect the command "continue" to do? What does your book tell?

Comment: Debugging is a good skill to have. If you want to become a professional software developer, or otherwise regularly develop software, it will be necessary.  Try running the code in a debugger. Set a breakpoint at `int i = 1;`. Then, follow the code step-by-step. Monitor the value of `i`.

Comment: Your program never terminates. When i reaches 3, none of the remaining code in your loop is ever executed, only the `continue` loops over and over.

Comment: i..e, the conclusion that 'continue' is breaking out of the loop has no basis in fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output is

> 1 2

but is your code ever completing? The continue statement occurs before your increment so the value of `i` remains as 3 indefinitely. You're looking at an infinite loop.

Make sure all code paths are incrementing your counter. For example

```
   if (i==3){
     i++;
     continue;
   }
   
   System.out.print(i);
   i++;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your loop condition and increment operation are seperated in your `while` loop. You could combine them. And I would recommend you start at `0`. Like,

```
int i = 0;
while (++i < 10) {
    if (i == 3) {
        continue;
    }
    System.out.print(i);
}
```

Or, do it without the `continue`. Like,

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    if (i != 3) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Or with an `IntStream`. Like,

```
IntStream.range(1, 10).filter(x -> x != 3).forEach(System.out::print);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried by your initial method, It worked, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your program enters an *infinite-loop* when *i* equals *3*.

Increment *i* prior to the *continue* statement.

```java
int i = 1;
while (i<=9){
    if (i==3){
        i++;
        continue;
    }
    System.out.print(i);
    i++;

}
```

Output

```
12456789
```

As a recommendation, if you plan on using *continue*, consider using the *[iterative for-loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)*.
Having *i* increment at one location can prove helpful as you build your *loop* code.

You could, also, use a *[do-while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)* loop, and increment *i* during the conditional statement.

```java
int i = 1;
do {
    if (i == 3) continue;
    System.out.print(i);
} while (++i <= 9);
```

On a final note, here is an example using a *[closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))*.

```java
IntStream.range(1, 10).forEach(value -> {
    if (value != 3) System.out.print(value);
});
```

Output

```
12456789
```

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter something like this, your should put in some print statements to see what is happening.  You can also slow down the process with a sleep statement.

```
public class Loops {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 1;
        while (i<=9){
            try {
              Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep for 1 second between iterations.
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        
            System.out.printf("Checking if %d == 3%n", i); 
           
            if (i==3){
                continue;
            }
            
            System.out.println(i);
            i++;
            
        }
}
```

prints

```
Checking if 1 == 3
1
Checking if 2 == 3
2
Checking if 3 == 3
Checking if 3 == 3
Checking if 3 == 3
Checking if 3 == 3
Checking if 3 == 3
Checking if 3 == 3
Checking if 3 == 3
Checking if 3 == 3
...
...
...
```

Notice that `i` will increment until it reaches `3`. Then since `i` now equals `3` it skips to the end of the loop, stuck at `3` forever.  So only `1` and `2` are printed.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution, However, since I am a fresher so I am unable to understand parts of it at this time, However will return to your solution after I progress further! Thank you so much!